# How do I launch a playbook to a host list by name or ip

Tags: python, ansible

I have an ansible playbook which I want to launch to a list of 100 hosts but I do not want the teams to be added in the host file I would like to create an external list, a txt or yml that contains the list of hosts to which it will be launched and this cast in this created order

could someone give me a guide?

Comment: Such external list would be the inventory. You may take advantage from [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directory should have something like this:
hosts
site.yaml

Your host file should be something like this (I am using cisco for the example, you can name it anything you want)

```
[ios]
host1
host2
ipaddress1
ipaddress2

[ios:vars]
ansible_connection=network_cli
anyOtherVarsHere
```

When you call the playbook you will specify your hosts file using the -i parameter.

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yaml
```

If your host file is selected somewhere else you can define the path:

```
ansible-playbook -i path/to/file/hosts site.yaml
```